# How to make RivaTuner load overclocking settings from the startup folder?

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-registry, overclocking

[RivaTuner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RivaTuner) starts through a registry entry at startup in order to load overclock settings. I want it to start from the startup folder instead. How would I do this?

Comment: please do not doublepost, stick to your original post!

Comment: I'm glad I posted again because this other guy actually had the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use msconfig to remove it from the registry entry. Create a shortcut to the same location that was in the registry (and msconfig under Startup, then "Command" column) and place it in the startup folder.

Comment: MSCONFIG is not a startup manager but a troubleshooting utility and therefore best left alone. if you want a startup manager, get Autoruns: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: It might not be a startup manager but it allows you to find the registry entries that he was looking for quickly and efficiently. I have been using it for as long as I can remember to modify startup settings without any issues. What is the point of installing yet ANOTHER program to do this when it's not necessary?

Comment: Autoruns has to be 'installed'? that's news to me. anyway, when you disable items via msconfig, you will receive a warning. in order to make the changes stick you will have to ignore the warning and boot the system permanently in 'selective startup' mode. a method rather unreliable and being on record for being 'forgettable' or not 'retaining' previous settings. recommendations to use msconfig as a startup manager are unsound advice.

Comment: Yes, autoruns has to be installed. http://tiny.cc/4molly I do not have it on my system and I'm running Windows 7. You know what IS on my system? MSCONFIG. I don't know what you are talking about the selective startup mode. After you change the settings you can choose to boot normally. The settings have always stuck for me and the fact you can uncheck an entry, it will stay there and you can enable it in the future if you want to go back to how it was. Your tone in the comments of YOUR answer to this question is also borderline rude. You were wrong the whole time too. He needs it to autostart.

Comment: Autoruns a single portable executive file distrubuted by Microsoft that does not require to be installed. Msconfig is not a startup manager and should not be used as such. In fact, it doesn't even reflect all startup items, again it is a diagnostic and troubleshooting utility. and as for the question at hand, i'm afraid i was right all along, RivaTuner DRIVER LEVEL settings (such as clock frequencies) are exclusively applied to the windows registry. other LOW LEVEL (note the difference) tweaks, however, are handled differently as they are accessing the graphics processor's registers.

Comment: Yes Molly, you are absolutely right about everything. Happy?

Comment: And thanks for pointing out the difference in Driver Level and Low Level (Even though you obviously don't understand the difference as your comments in this single question are contradictory). I guess a degree in Computer Science doesn't qualify me to understand such complex concepts. At least I can admit when I'm wrong. You have two people pointing out that you are wrong and you continue to argue.

Comment: i certainly do not argoue anything, i was merely quoting from the software developer's FAQ (right from the horse's mouth if you wish) regarding the "driver level settings for clock frequencies". and as for your vitriolic rants: i don't wish to discuss this any further, have a good day.

Comment: lol, my rants? ok. You have yourself a good day too.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want it to use the registry
>   key.

Then RivaTuner may not be for you as in its core RivaTuner is a registry tweaker (all the driver's settings are stored in the registry).

Comment: That's fine, I just want to be able to make it load the overclock settings by sending command line options to the program.

Comment: but that's not how RivaTuner works, it's not a program that loads some miraculous GPU tweaks when it starts, all it does is modifying the graphics driver settings at registry level.

Comment: I know how RivaTuner works.  I don't care if it messes with the registry.  I just don't want it to load from the registry.  You're not understanding.

Comment: you don't need RivaTuner running at all. use the program to select the tweaks. these tweaks are then applied to the registry and will work whether RivaTuner is running or not. you can even remove RivaTuner completely from your hard drive, the tweaks will still work.

Comment: That's not true.  If I use RivaTuner to set my GPU to operate at a higher clock frequency, if I reboot Windows and don't allow RivaTuner to run, then the GPU will run at the factory set frequency.

Comment: Quote (from the RivaTuner FAQ): Q: Can I close RivaTuner after changing the driver's settings? Will the tweaks have an effect in this case? A: Yes, of course. All the driver's settings are stored in the registry so you can safely close RivaTuner or even remove it from your hard drive, but the tweaks will still work.

Comment: I don't care about the stupid tweaks.  I'm talking about the driver level settings for core clock, shader clock, and memory clock.  These cannnot be controlled simply by setting registry settings.  On the same page as these in RivaTuner there's an option that says "Apply overclocking at Windows startup"  If this box is checked then it makes RivaTuner run on startup so that it can change those settings from factory default.  If it were simply a matter of editing the registry then it wouldn't need to do that.

Comment: "I'm talking about the driver level". again, quote: "At the DRIVER LEVEL RivaTuner changes the settings VIA THE REGISTRY and directly calls the driver's functions ... e.g. query and SET the clock frequencies"

Comment: Yeah, well whatever.  The point is that it has to do something at startup otherwise the card won't run at the overclocked settings.  I've even verified this with other programs that show gpu statistics.

Comment: here's another quote from the FAQ that may very well be what you're looking for: "RivaTuner adds itself with the /S COMMAND LINE SWITCH to the autorun registry key when you enable any LOW LEVEL settings (e.g. overclocking or color correction) at Windows startup. When this command line switch is specified, RivaTuner loads itself at Windows startup, executes startup daemon (the procedure that configures startup settings depending on the settings you've made) and unloads itself from memory immediately."

Comment: Yeah, that's true.  So you see, I can't just uninstall RivaTuner if I want to use overclock settings.  RivaTuner has to actually do something besides just writing registry keys in order to overclock the GPU.

Comment: Q: How does RivaTuner work? Is it just a registry tweaker? A: Yes, it was a registry tweaking utility in the beginning. Now RivaTuner can work in two modes and tweak your graphics subsystem either at the driver level or at low level.

Depending on what mode is being used it's possible the software has to run at startup. Yes there is a /S switch but it is each user's choice how they want to run their system.